# Minecraft 1.12.2: Add all items from that already exist in the chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-technic-pack

I played Stardew Valley, and there was this neat button whenever you looked inside a chest. If you clicked it, all the items that were in your inventory would be deposited into the chest, so long as the chest had the same items.

This meant you could have chests organized, and if your inventory was full of stuff after a long day, you could deposit all your items within a few seconds just as the chests are organized.

[image]

Is it possible to have this feature in [Minecraft Technic The 1.12.2 Pack](https://www.technicpack.net/modpack/the-1122-pack.1406454)? Such as an additional client side mod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YOU CAN USE INVENTORY TWEAKS, BUT I SUGGEST QUARK MOD FOR ITS SIMPLE ASPECTS**

Yes, Bro, Quark mod is the one you are looking for but you have a lot of other things and feature in it but you can totally customize it and add only the feature you want!

*-If you only want this you can enable this in Management and disable other features Client for newer versions-*

Six buttons are added to Chest interfaces in 1.12.2 and they do the following:

·Sort the chest
·Deposit your entire inventory (not Hotbar, armour or off-hand) in the chest.
·Same as the previous, but only for items that the chest has at least one of inside.
·Sort your inventory.
·Extract all items from the chest into your inventory.
·Extract all items from the chest that you have at least one of in your inventory.

[image: Chest Buttons - Quark mod]
other features of Quark mod at https://quark.vazkii.net/#features

Hope this answered your question pal.

Comment: Thank you! This mod came with the 1.12.2 pack, so I just enabled it on my client and the server and now it's working great!!! The specific option I enabled was `B:"Chest buttons"=true` in */config/quark.cfg*

Comment: Happy that it helped!